# Routing Issue Dash Visualization to Django App

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I am trying to add a simple bar chart to my app but while going through a tutorial, I've added in the bottom portion to my Settings.py code and now my app will not load at all. I've tried adjusting this line to just 'routing.application' and moving it to the bottom of my code but neither has worked. Any thoughts?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\channels\management\commands\runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    application=self.get_application(options),
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\channels\management\commands\runserver.py", line 132, in get_application
    return StaticFilesWrapper(get_default_application())
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 30, in get_default_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'django_dash.routing
```

Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'x'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
    'bootstrap4',
    'dpd_static_support',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

        # Adding additional MIDDLEWARE
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django_plotly_dash.middleware.BaseMiddleware',
    'django_plotly_dash.middleware.ExternalRedirectionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'



# 

# Define folder location of 'static' folder
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# 'django_dash': django app name
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_dash', 'static'),
    ]

# Static content of Plotly components that should
# be handled by the Django staticfiles infrastructure

PLOTLY_COMPONENTS = [
    'dash_core_components',
    'dash_html_components',
    'dash_bootstrap_components',
    'dash_renderer',
    'dpd_components',
    'dpd_static_support',
]

# Staticfiles finders for locating dash app assets and related files (Dash static files)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [

    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashAssetFinder',
    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashComponentFinder',
    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashAppDirectoryFinder',
]

# Channels config, to use channel layers

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 6379),],
        },
    },
}
# Adding ASGI Application
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'django_dash.routing.application'
# ---------- Add Django Dash end --------------------------------
```

Dash Visual:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

# Read plotly example dataframe to plot barchart
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='India'")

external_stylesheets=['https://codepen.io/amyoshino/pen/jzXypZ.css']

# Important: Define Id for Plotly Dash integration in Django
app = DjangoDash('dash_integration_id')

app.css.append_css({
"external_url": external_stylesheets
})
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        # Adding one extar Div
        html.Div([
            html.H1(children='Multiple Application'),
            html.H3(children='Indian Population over time'),
            html.Div(children='Dash: Python framework to build web application'),
        ], className = 'row'),

        html.Div([
            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(
                    id='bar-chart',
                    figure={
                        'data': [
                            {'x': df['year'], 'y': df['pop'], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                        ],
                        'layout': {
                            'title': 'Bar Chart Visualization'
                        }
                    }
                ),
            ], className = 'six columns'),

            # Adding one more app/component
            html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(
                    id='line-chart',
                    figure={
                        'data': [
                            {'x': df['year'], 'y': df['pop'], 'type': 'line', 'name': 'SF'},
                        ],
                        'layout': {
                            'title': 'Line Chart Visualization'
                        }
                    }
                )
            ], className = 'six columns')

        ], className = 'row')
    ])
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(8052, debug=False)
```